# Where to keep persistent, executable files in Container-Optimized OS

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-optimized-os

I'm using a **Container-Optimized OS** on GCP's **Compute Engine**. I'm mounting a directory volume to my container, the problem is that my application creates and **executes** files in this volume, but Container-Optimized OS doesn't allow executing in a home directory. Where should I keep the volume then?

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security), the only suitable path is `/var/lib/[google|docker|toolbox]`, but is it a correct place to keep such files? Will I stumble upon some issues if I keep my persistent, executable files there? Or maybe should I switch to a different OS (eg. Ubuntu)?

Comment: Can you not mount under `mnt/disks`?

Comment: Do you run a container on COS?

Comment: @DazWilkin Yea I think additional drives, mounted under mnt/disks is a way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to @DazWilkin, and verified by @Gieted. Mounting additional drives is a good solution.

Here is a documentation on how to [mount additional drives](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/disks-and-filesystem#mounting_and_formatting_disks) on container-optimized OS